# Swift save image to server - multipart/form-data

Tags: php, post, swift, multipart

Ok, I am stuck and I need help.

Once I get past this part I should be able to finish this app for a Non-Profit in a few days. I have searched and searched for two full days and I can't get this done. So, Here is what I need help with:

1) I have a controller that allows a user to take a picture of a horse or select from pictures and then tag that horse by name.

2) This works fine, but now i want to be able to save that file on my server. I do this via HTML so i have the php code down already and I will post that part.

3) The part I need help with is getting the Swift code (Multipart / Form-Data to work).

```
<?PHP include("This has my connection info");?>

<?php
function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
{
    if(empty($imagetype)){
        return false;
    }
    switch($imagetype){
        case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
        case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
        case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
        case 'image/png': return '.png';
        default: return false;
    }

    if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() ){
        $Name = addslashes ($_POST['Name']);
        $User = addslashes ($_POST['Fullname']); 
    }

    if (empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])){
        echo "You need to use a valid image";   
    } else if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {
        $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
        $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
        $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
        $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
        $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
        $target_path = "Horses/Images/".$imagename;
        $temp_path = "Horses/Temp/".$imagename;

        if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $temp_path)) {
            compress($temp_path, $target_path, 70);
            $query_upload="INSERT into images_table (Name, images_path, username) VALUES ('$Name', '$target_path', '$User')";
            mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error()); 
            echo "Thank you $User for your submission";   
        } else {
            exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
        }
    }
}
?>;
```

The image inside swift is "camerView.image"

How do I get code this inside swift to rename the file to "uploaded image" and sent over?    Any help is greatly appreciated.

FYI: here is the start of what I have after the button is pushed on the controller:

```
@IBAction func PostImage(sender: UIButton) {
    if (self.tagTableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow() == nil || cameraView.image == nil){
        var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        alertView.title = "Oopsy!"
        alertView.message = "Select an Image and Tag a horse"
        alertView.delegate = self
        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alertView.show()
    } else {
        var horseIndex = tagTableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row
        var selectedHorse = self.horses[horseIndex!]
        var TagHorse:NSString = selectedHorse.Name as NSString
    }
}
```